# Global Exception Logging Play 2.4

Tags: java, logging, playframework, configuration, playframework-2.4

I have a strange behavior since I have passed from Play 2.3 to Play 2.4.

When an exception is thrown, it is never log to the console. The serveur respond a InternalServerError to the clien but the exception is not shwon in the console. It's pretty hard to debug this way...

have I missed an important confiuration changement or something like this ?

Comment: Have you defined your own HttpErrorHandler?

Comment: @JulienLafont No I haven't, I have just define a custom Action for CORS setting

Comment: FWIK you forgot nothing, sounds like a weird bug. Could you try to reproduce the problem with a minimal project and share it?